# Read varying part from text file (VBA)

Tags: vba, text-files, wildcard

From the following two example files I would like to only have all lines that start with #COLUMNINFO to be read into an excelfile, and each line be seperated using a comma as deliminator.

I'm having trouble to just read only those lines, since the line numbers change per file. My attempt so far was to use a piece of code similar to:

```
Do Until ts.ReadLine = "#COLUMN= " & [?]
Loop
```

And read the file from that line on, but I can't seem to use wildcards in combination with .ReadFile.

Any help is welcome.

[Example 1](https://drive.google.com/open?id=149i9hm4VG6-Szni2UZoIAmdRo0X1cqGB)

[Example 2](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1rhe0cRrxczcXf2gGxe54Xeq42sNpXPiu)

I've eddited my code and this is the updated result. Somehow the 'Do While Loop' fails.
Edit:

```
Sub InfoExtractorTest()

    Dim fso As Scripting.FileSystemObject
    Dim ts As Scripting.TextStream
    Dim textline As String
    Dim CommaPosition As Integer

    Set fso = New Scripting.FileSystemObject

    Set ts = fso.OpenTextFile(Environ("Userprofile") & "\Desktop\VBA Test\GEFExtractor\Example GEF's\362B-S142.gef")

    Do While Not ts.AtEndOfStream

      'Reads indiviual lines from file
        Data = ts.ReadLine
        If InStr(1, UCase(Data), "#COLUMNINFO") > 0 Then

        textline = ts.ReadLine
        CommaPosition = InStr(textline, ",")

            Do Until CommaPosition = 0
                ActiveCell.Value = Left(textline, CommaPosition - 1)
                ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
                textline = Right(textline, Len(textline) - CommaPosition)
                CommaPosition = InStr(textline, ",")
            Loop

            ActiveCell.Value = textline
            ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).End(xlToLeft).Select

        End If
    Loop

    ts.Close
    Set fso = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Your thinking is correct. Take a look at `Instr` function. Or if you want wildcard then take a look at `Like` operator.

Comment: If an answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark and upvoting by clicking the up arrow. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Like this [link](https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/420472-string-starts-vba.html) shows you want to use 'like'.

```
Do Until ts.ReadLine Like "#COLUMN= *" & [?]
Loop
```

This will let you use asterisk as a wildcard

Comment: I tried that too, but it doesn't work. Even if I have a working code, and apply 'Like' operator and replace a letter with an asterisk I get a runtime error '62' at said line.

Comment: I figured it out. I should've replaced the first '#' also with an asterisk sign, it sort of messed up the code appartently. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly, try something like the following:

```
Do While Not ts.AtEndofStream
   data = ts.ReadLine

   If InStr(1, UCase(data), "#COLUMNINFO") > 0 then
      'do something
   End If
Loop

ts.close
```

I assume you are using `FileSystemObject` to read the file.

Comment: I used your comment and that of the other respondants to add in a a 'Do While Loop', but it's not working properly yet. I've added the complete code in my editted post, could you give me a push in the right direction to making it work?

Comment: With your modified code, if the first line of your file does not contain `COLUMNINFO` then you will not go into the loop.  Is that the case here?  Irregardless, if you structure your modified code like I showed above it should give you what you need.

Comment: I´ve implemented your suggestion (see most recent edit). Though, it structurally skips one line. So, while the condition is met: the 1st, 3rd and 5th line are not extracted, but the 2nd, 4th and 6th are.

Comment: It's because you have an extra `ReadLine`.  Remove `textline = ts.ReadLine` (and replace every `textline` reference with `data`)  and you should be good.